# why are my if and elif statements not running properly?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi so I've changed the code from past questions to try and simplify it, however now I'm having another problem,

So I have this code which checks for a certain role and changes the roles, however when I input the command into discord which is //leave @name time reason, neither the 'if' or 'elif' statements run.

I get no feedback, no errors, just no reaction from the bot whatsoever.

Here's the code, if someone can tell me what's going on for the statements to not run properly I'd appreciate it.

(I've tried interchanging the 'elif' statements with 'if' statements but to no avail.)

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(876994087214018571)
async def leave(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: str = '', *, reason: str = ''):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    smod = ctx.guild.get_role(851617257138028645)
    amod = ctx.guild.get_role(848057125283954688)
    if member.has_role(848032880709074944):
        await member.add_roles(loa)
        await member.remove_roles(mod)
        await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")
    elif member.has_role(851617257138028645):
        await member.add_roles(loa)
        await member.remove_roles(smod)
        await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")
    elif member.has_role(848057125283954688):
        await member.add_roles(loa)
        await member.remove_roles(amod)
        await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")
    modLogEmbed = discord.Embed(title='Leave Logs',
                                description="A member of Staff is going on leave! " + '<@' + str(member.id) + '>', color=0x000000)
    modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Time",
                          value=(time), inline=False)
    modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Reason for Leave:",
                          value=(reason), inline=False)
    modLogEmbed.set_footer(text="LeaveManager Bot")
    modLogEmbed.set_author(name='Leave Manager')
    botLogChannel = client.get_channel(874959002172268685)
    await botLogChannel.send(embed=modLogEmbed)
```

Also I really do sincerely apologise for the way the code is set out, I genuinely can't figure out how to get it to layout properly like other members questions.

Comment: You should check your console first, and maybe add a `else send('I didn't find any role')` to check. We can't tell where's the problem if you're not providing any err message(and where's the program stop or even raise an exception).

Comment: alright, I still simplified your question and answer it below, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `member.has_roles` is the problem, member does not have the attribute 'has_role'

maybe try this- using `find` and `lambda` to find if your `id` in any element of `roles`

I've test it using other role, it works fine.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role(876994087214018571)
    async def leave(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: str = '', *, reason: str = ''):
        if not member:
            member = ctx.author
        loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
        mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
        smod = ctx.guild.get_role(851617257138028645)
        amod = ctx.guild.get_role(848057125283954688)

        result = find(lambda x: x.id == 848032880709074944, member.roles)
        if result:
            await member.add_roles(loa)
            await member.remove_roles(mod)
            await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")

        await ctx.send('done')
```